# Subtract minutes and seconds from two varchar epoch time columns

Tags: oracle

I have 2 columns where the date is stored as epoch time in miliseconds. The column is of varchar type.

my_table:

```
id | user_name | date_added    | date_modified |
1  | John | 1629732833000 | 1629735653000
```

I am having some trouble with subtracting the minutes and seconds from the columns. I wrote the sql in many ways to get the difference from date_modified and date_added and i don't get any value returned when i run it.

Example of selects i tried: (i edited the user column to user_name because the name of the column is just an example and i didn't realize the moment i wrote the post. Not the issue for sure, as I've seen in the comments)

```
select to_char(CAST(DATE '1970-01-01' +(1 / 24 / 60 / 60 / 1000) * (t.date_modified - t.date_added) AS TIMESTAMP), 'yyyy-mm-dd HH24:MI') * 24 *60 * 60  from my_table t;
```

```
     select (TO_DATE('1970-01-01','YYYY-MM-DD') + t.date_modified / 86400000 -  TO_DATE('1970-01-01','YYYY-MM-DD') + t.date_added / 86400000)/24/60  as minutes1 
from my_table t
where t.user_name = 'John';
```

What i would like to get as a result is( edited to 47 min because that is the actual value, it's just an example of how it should look)

```
result: 47:00 (mi:ss).
```

I guess there's something i'm missing here. I searched for possible problems and i can't figure out why i am not getting anything. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please, describe how do you get `50:30` for this two values, because the difference is 47 minutes

Comment: If you are getting no rows back then the `user = 'John'` filter looks suspicious; `user` is a reserved word so you can't have a column called that unless it is a quoted identifier, and used unquoted it's a function that returns *your* username. So unless you are logged in as `John' (with a quoted username) that will never be matched. Also can the different (which is indeed 47 minutes in the example) be more than 24 hours, and if so how would you want to show that?

Comment: @astentx the 50:30 result was just an example, I know there are about 50 minutes difference, pease don't take it literally.

Comment: @AlexPoole Well, the column in my_table is not really called user, it's just an example. This is not the culprit.

Answer (score 3):

You could convert both epoch values to dates or timestamps - both your example values end 000 so it doesn't look like you need milisecond precision, but assuming you do that could be done with:

```
(timestamp '1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC' + (date_modified * interval '0.001' second))
  - (timestamp '1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC' + (date_added * interval '0.001' second))
```

(ignoring leap seconds, which is a separate discussion).

But you could just subtract the two values, as numbers, and convert that number of miliseconds directly:

```
(date_modified - date_added) * interval '0.001' second
```

Both of those give you an interval result of:

```
+000000000 00:47:00.000000000
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=e8b92d4b17c18831b749839c39dfb4cf)

You can't format that directly as a string, but you could extract the components, or add to a nominal timestamp and format that; how you handle that depends on whether you can have gaps spanning more than a day, and how you want to display those.

---

I assume you've changed the column names for posting, as you can't have a column called `user` unless it's created as a quoted identifier - which would be confusing, at best. If you are adding a filter like `where user = 'John'` to a query then that will compare [your username](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/USER.html#GUID-AD0B927B-EFD4-4246-89B4-2D55AB3AF531) to that string, and it's unlikely you are logged into an account call "John", so the condition will never be true. If the column does have a [quoted identifier](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Database-Object-Names-and-Qualifiers.html#GUID-75337742-67FD-4EC0-985F-741C93D918DA) then you have to quote the references to it as well.

Comment: I edited the column name in my post. ' User' is not the name of my real column (you were right), i didn't realize when i created the example. I don't need miliseconds precision, indeed.

Answer (score 2):

Full example in details in parts:
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=1cf120209dcd47d98bdb1e88f2736870

1. I would suggest to create a function for converting epoch to oracle timestamp:

```sql
create or replace
  function epoch_time_to_timestamp(ep_time in int) 
    return timestamp deterministic as
    PRAGMA UDF;
  begin
      return timestamp'1970-01-01 00:00:00'+numtodsinterval(ep_time/1000,'second');
  end;
```

so you could easily reuse it. Pragma UDF allows it to run quickly in SQL, `deterministic` clause helps to avoid multiple function execution.

2. after converting values to `timestamp`, you can easily operate with them, the result type will be `interval`: (Part 2 in DBFiddle)

```sql
select
    date_modified-date_added as delta
from (
    select
        t.id
       ,t."USER" -- user is a bad name for column, since it's reserved word for "user" function
       ,epoch_time_to_timestamp(date_added) as date_added
       ,epoch_time_to_timestamp(date_modified) as date_modified
    from my_table t
    );
```

3. Then you need just to return your interval in the required format. You have a lot of different variants: first of all `to_char(ds interval)` returns it in the format "+000000000 00:47:00.000000000", so you can even use simple string functions. But also you can add this interval to date or timestamp and use `to_char()` function defined for date or timesetamp to format it as you wish:

```sql
select
    substr(to_char(delta),15,5) subst,
    regexp_substr(delta, ' \d\d:(\d\d:\d\d)\.\d+',1,1,'',1) as reg_substr,
    to_char(date'1970-01-01'+delta, 'mi:ss') date_to_char
from (
    select date_modified-date_added as delta 
    from (
        select
            t.id
           ,t."USER" -- user is a bad name for column, since it's reserved word for "user" function
           ,epoch_time_to_timestamp(date_added) as date_added
           ,epoch_time_to_timestamp(date_modified) as date_modified
        from my_table t
        )
    )
```

Full example with test data: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=3638399bf7205981edaafe40ae57d52a

```sql
with 
  function epoch_time_to_timestamp(ep_time in int) 
    return timestamp deterministic as
  begin
      return timestamp'1970-01-01 00:00:00'+numtodsinterval(ep_time/1000,'second');
  end;
  my_table(id, "USER", date_added, date_modified) as (
    select 1 ,'John', '1629732833000','1629735653000' from dual
  )
select
    substr(to_char(delta),15,5) subst,
    regexp_substr(delta, ' \d\d:(\d\d:\d\d)\.\d+',1,1,'',1) as reg_substr,
    to_char(date'1970-01-01'+delta, 'mi:ss') date_to_char
from (
    select date_modified-date_added as delta 
    from (
        select
            t.id
           ,t."USER" -- user is a bad name for column, since it's reserved word for "user" function
           ,epoch_time_to_timestamp(date_added) as date_added
           ,epoch_time_to_timestamp(date_modified) as date_modified
        from my_table t
        )
    )
;
```

Comment: ps. Oh, spent to much time to write it in details :D

Comment: typo here = `s/to/too/`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the end result should be in string data type, and it should always show minutes and seconds (even if minutes are more than 60), you could do something like this - not going through date/time functions at any point:

```
with
  my_table (id, user_name, date_added, date_modified) as (
    select 1, 'John', '1629732833000', '1629735653000' from dual
  )
, prep (sec) as (
    select (to_number(date_modified) - to_number(date_added))/1000
    from   my_table
    where  id = 1
  )
  select trunc(sec/60) || ':' || to_char(mod(sec, 60), 'fm00') as min_sec
  from   prep
;


MIN_SEC
-------
47:00
```

The first subquery in the `with` clause is just for testing (remove it, use actual table and column names in the second subquery in the `with` clause). Also, I assume you will filter by `id`, not by `name`.

If you ever need milliseconds, you can just change the format model in the `to_char` call at the end; the query will work without any other changes.